# Firebase app - keep track of the time of user's last access?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I noticed Firebase stores user creation time and user login time ny default, but not the time the user last accessed the app. Would I need to store this info separately?
I notice some of my users show as having logged in weeks ago, yet I have been using the app everyday. Keeping track of when the user last accessed the app is useful for admin purposes.

Answer (score 1):

> Would I need to store this info separately?

Yes, you should record whatever value you need per-user in a database of your choosing.  It doesn't have to be Firestore as you tagged here.